# Removing a num from a string in a list of numbers

Tags: python-3.x

An example like:

```
print("1.", get_list_nums_without_9([589775, 677017, 34439, 48731548,     782295632, 181967909]))
print("2.", get_list_nums_without_9([6162, 29657355, 5485406, 422862350, 74452, 480506, 2881]))
print("3.", get_list_nums_without_9([292069010, 73980, 8980155, 921545108, 75841309, 6899644])) 
print("4.", get_list_nums_without_9([]))

nums = [292069010, 73980, 8980155, 21545108, 7584130, 688644, 644908219, 44281, 3259, 8527361, 2816279, 985462264, 904259, 3869, 609436333, 36915, 83705, 405576, 4333000, 79386997]
print("5.", get_list_nums_without_9(nums))
```

I'm trying to get number list without 9. If the list is empty or if all of the numbers in the list contain the digit 9, the function should return an empty list. I tried the function below, it doesn't work.

```
def get_list_nums_without_9(a_list):
    j=0
    for i in a_list:
    a_list[j]=i.rstrip(9)
    j+=1
    return a_list
```

expected:

```
1. [677017, 48731548]
2. [6162, 5485406, 422862350, 74452, 480506, 2881]
3. []
4. []
5. [21545108, 7584130, 688644, 44281, 8527361, 83705, 405576, 4333000]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your lists contain *integers*. To remove the ones containing `9` the best way is to test if `9` belongs to the number *as string* and rebuild the output using a list comprehension with a conditional.

(Besides, `rstrip` removes the trailing chars of a string. Not suitable *at all* for your problem)

```
def get_list_nums_without_9(a_list):
    return [x for x in a_list if "9" not in str(x)]
```

testing with your data:

```
>>> numbers = [
...    [589775, 677017, 34439, 48731548, 782295632, 181967909],
...    [6162, 29657355, 5485406, 422862350, 74452, 480506, 2881],
...    [292069010, 73980, 8980155, 921545108, 75841309, 6899644],
...    [],
...    [292069010, 73980, 8980155, 21545108, 7584130, 688644, 644908219, 
...     44281, 3259, 8527361, 2816279, 985462264, 904259, 3869, 609436333, 
...     36915, 83705, 405576, 4333000, 79386997]
... ]

>>> for i, l in enumerate(numbers, 1):
...    print("{}. {}".format(i, get_list_nums_without_9(l)))
1. [677017, 48731548]
2. [6162, 5485406, 422862350, 74452, 480506, 2881]
3. []
4. []
5. [21545108, 7584130, 688644, 44281, 8527361, 83705, 405576, 4333000]
```

Comment: But this input should give you `[21545108, 7584130, 688644]` if you follow the examples in the OP's post.  He's not modifying numbers, he's dropping them.

Comment: @cdlane I read a bit quickly. Thanks for pointing that out, edited.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to replace anything in the list, you want to generate a new list based on what you detect in the old list:

```
def get_list_nums_without_9(numbers):
    sans_9 = []

    for number in numbers:
        if '9' not in str(number):
            sans_9.append(number)

    return sans_9
```

This will get you an empty list if there are no valid numbers.